# Ubuntu "randomly" gets unreachable (network)

Tags: networking, server

I have a home server running Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel:4.15.0-74), hosting a few Samba file shares and some services. I only access it from the local network.

Sometimes the server gets completely unreachable, both the file shares and the services and I can't ping or ssh in. I couldn't figure out a pattern yet, but it might be related to restarting the router (the last incident happened some time after I restarted the router)

I usually plug a keyboard+monitor in and try to troubleshoot and I noticed the followings:

1. The OS is not frozen. I can interact with it via the keyboard
2. The network works fine (from the server out): I can ping internal and external addresses and curl external sites
3. I tried to turn off the firewall, but that doesn't solve the problem (+ why would that randomly cause a problem when works otherwise)
4. The services are running fine and there is no error or anything in their app log
5. Disabling and enabling the wireless adapter doesn't help (with ifconfig ... on/off)
6. Restarting the machine solves the problem

The installation is pretty vanilla, I didn't add any external firewall installation or anything network related. It's connecting to the router via WLAN and the router uses DHCP. I access the services/shares by the local IP, but I always check if it has the "correct" IP after I restart the adapter/machine.

I am really clueless what can the problem be or in what direction to move forward, but it is really annoying. 
Do you have any idea how to solve or troubleshoot this issue?

I would be happy with a work-around too, I could write a script that restarts the machine when this happens, but I can't even find a "trigger" for that since from the machine the network works fine and everything looks green and correct.

Edit:

/etc/netplan/*.yaml:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        CableBox-0741:
          password: <password>
```

lshw (the ethernet port is not used):

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: f8:d1:11:ce:84:a6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-74-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.10.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7300000-f730ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 10
       serial: 90:2b:34:6e:f9:e1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7200000-f723ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

lshc -C memory:

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: F10
       date: 08/09/2012
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 4
       slot: CPU Internal L1
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: CPU Internal L2
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal write-through instruction
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: CPU Internal L3
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 7
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 0
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: KHX1600C9D3/4GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: D72E79CB
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 2
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: KHX1600C9D3/4GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: D42EF3CB
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        503M        121M        3.6M        7.1G        7.0G
Swap:          979M         47M        932M
```

Also to answer the questions in the comments:
The router is unfortunately physically inaccessible (the technic room opens from a closet, Narnia style). This is the reason why it's wireless connection. Also, due to this I rarely reset it physically (either button or unplugging) and just reboot it via the web interface.

The router is a SagemCom FAST3890_D0.

I did setup a reserved address for all of our devices. I also verify after each reboot (after attaching the keyboard) that it has the IP address that I expect it to have.

As mentioned above, I rarely do reset physically and didn't do it when I faced the issue last time.

It is my old (4 years old) desktop PC that I turned into a "server". Only basic stuff really runs on it and it rarely goes above 20% load CPU/memory-vise.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: I added the output of the two commands. Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the comment

Comment: May `netstat -s` will help. Just take a look what goes in and what goes out. To get a better overview about the time it will happen, I'd recommend the tool `smokeping` (https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) on a 3rd system.

Comment: No clues yet. Still accumulating data. Any reason that you don't use an ethernet cable to the router? What brand router? Do you know how to setup a reserved address for the server in your router? Have you actually unplugged the router from AC, counted to 10, and then re-plugged the router? Is this a desktop, or laptop? Show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: I added the relevant info to the post :)